# How to get the default system color in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicolor, swift5

I'm currently building an iOS app using Swift, and I just wanna get the light gray-ish default system color used in the tabBar and the navigationbar, and apply that color to another button.

I've looked through various sites but I can't find it anywhere that has the exact property name. Is there any way to get the property name or the RGB of it?

I'd appreciate for your help.

Comment: you want RGB of Default system gray colour??

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not simply a predefined color. Both views use transparency so the underlying view will shine through (is the `isTranslucent` flag is set to true). Use the view debugger to inspect the view hierarchy.

Comment: @taikichi every UIview you are creating is always created with white color. but there is no default color thing in iOS.

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology Yeah exactly. However, I also found that the default system color changes? so it would probably better to get the versatile color property if there is.

Comment: @inexcitus Thanks! I'll try to use that solution but I'm not using storyboard..is it fine to do so?

Comment: @AyAz Nono not the view that I'm creating, it's the preset color of the navigation bar and the tab bar. That light gray color you get when you didn't set the color to it.

Answer (score 2):

probably [systemGray](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173143-systemgray) is what you want

Comment: Also check [Standard Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors) and [UI Element Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/ui_element_colors), which could change depending on Light/Dark theme